# How to copy a line from polygon to an other polygon QGIS 2.6.1

Tags: qgis, polygon, line

1. I have a polygon(state) now the state divide into two.
2. I have a new polygon with two state.

I want to copy only the new border(line) which divides the two state from new polygon to old.

I am trying to select a line from a polygon but it is not possible.

Comment: It is not possible to select a line from a polygon, they are two completely different geometry types. Perhaps it would be best to transfer the attributes from one to the other.

Comment: u mean merge polygon attributes.

Comment: Sort of, you export the centroids (labels) with the correct attributes and the lines of the new polygons then create polygons from those boundaries and labels... new geometry, old attributes. As long as the centriods fall in the correct polygon it will work well. I don't recommend doing this for layers with lots of polygons but as you've only got two it should be easy.

Comment: Selecting a line from a polygon needs an interim step of splitting polygon to segments but I am not sure what you would like to do next.

Comment: I thought of adding line to polygon, Copy paste.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach to extract line from polygon and merge line with polygon.

1. Convert polygon to line. Goto: Vector -> Geometry tools -> Polygons to lines.
2. Retain the lines u want and delete the rest of the line.
   To delete, load the new layer select Toggle Editing then Goto:
   Edit -> Split features

Now draw line on top of line u want to delete new node will appear on the line.Now click on Select Features from Attribute toolbar and select the line and press delete key ( I followed the above approach for deletion because by default it is selecting all the lines for deletion).

[image]

3. Now merge the TWO-shape file (Polygon and Line).
   Goto: Vector -> Data management Tools -> Merge shape Files to One

[image]

Check the “Select by layers in the folder” option, Browse the input files and generate new shape file.